# Secure rating form

Tags: php

I have a list with purchased items and just like on ebay or any other site which allows user feedback, I want users to send feedback. But I'm not sure how to secure everything.

Below is just a quick example:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
      //this is where i need the item id. But how do I make sure that users don't mess with the form and change the item id?
    }
?>

<ul>

  <li id="1">
    Item title
    <form action="" method="post"><button type="submit" name="like">Like</button></form>
  </li>

  <li id="2">
    Another title
    <form action="" method="post"><button type="submit" name="like">Like</button></form>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Even if I would use jQuery to grab the li id, someone can still edit the id and vote for some other title.

I also wanted to add a hidden input, but that's editable also.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to check on the server whether the user is allowed to do that.

Comment: Research [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how do I make sure that users don't mess with the form and change the item id?

You don't.  They can change the ID.

Assume that this is true and that it's outside of your control and the next logical step becomes: **Validate the operation in server-side code**.

Allow the user to post the form with whatever ID they want.  You pre-fill that ID in JavaScript or a hidden form field to the ID you *expect*, of course.  Don't force the user to enter an ID or anything silly like that.  But just use whatever you would normally use for this form.

Then, in server-side code, when handling the form post, validate that the logged-in user is *authorized* to submit/modify data for that ID.  Check that the user has actually bought the product they're reviewing, for example.  However you want to validate, logically, that the user is permitted to do what they're doing, you perform that validation in server-side code *when receiving the form post*, not when generating the form to be posted.

If the user isn't authorized (they changed the ID), handle that however you like.  An error page, a warning message, ignore it, it's up to you.